# Add user generated comments to existing javadoc

Tags: documentation, javadoc, comments

Our team develops software for BlackBerry devices. The BlackBerry API (javadocs) is poorly documented, and sometimes even outdated.

What we would like to do is import this existing documentation into an online system that could then be edited/commented by developers/users - thus creating a far richer user generated API documentation. Maybe we can even add sample code / references to the appropriate methods.

Is there a simple way for doing the above? Any available commenting systems that can integrate with javadocs?

I have done extensive search for a solution on the internet but couldn't find any available software solution to this problem.

Comment: Why don't you edit the source?

Comment: I do not own the source for the libraries. The libraries are propriety, we only get the stub jar files and the javadocs.